# Is it possible to mix in trait in abstract class but make it specific to each subclass in Scala?

Tags: scala, abstract-class, traits

I wrote some code for Logic Expressions in Scala and I was wondering if I could find a way to mix in a trait into an abstract class, so I don't have to extend it in every subclass. Here is what I've got:

```
abstract class LogicExpression

case class Literal(lit:String, not:Boolean) extends LogicExpression with Ordered[Literal]
case class Conjunction(lits:Seq[Literal]) extends LogicExpression with Ordered[Conjunction]
...
```

I want every case class to be only Comparable to another instance of itself (Literal with Literal, Conjunction only with Conjunction, etc) but I would like to extend the trait in the abstract class so I don't have to repeat it on every subclass. Is this possible?

I tried

```
abstract class LogicExpression extends Ordered[LogicFormula]
```

but that would also allow comparing Literal with Conjunction for example.

Comment: Do all case classes extend `LogicExpression`?

Comment: yes, every case class extends LogicExpression

Comment: Can you always deduce an ordering only from using the base `LogicExpression`?

Comment: no, you need the specific parameters of the case class (for example in Literal you sort by lit:String)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
sealed trait LogicExpression[T <: LogicExpression[T]] extends Ordered[T]

case class SomeExpression() extends LogicExpression[SomeExpression] {
  override def compare(that: SomeExpression) = ???
}
```